# Can a nested/inner class see the private members of its containing/outer class?

Tags: c#

I had this impression that a nested class could access the private members of a containing class and I don't remember why I believed this.

Is this true? And if it is, I've forgotten the syntax to use to access the outer class' members from within a nested class.

Comment: Why not just check this yourself..?

Comment: [Yes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173120.aspx); from the sixth result [from searching Google for "nested classes"](https://www.google.com/search?q=nested+classes). [I didn't even bother to include "c#"!]

Comment: @Daniel: I typed this question after checking on my own, because I couldn't remember the syntax. Believe me, I've remembered to check it and checked it many times. Just couldn't remember the syntax. I guess it must have been in Java, and that must've been why I got confused.

Comment: @KennyEvitt: Google results are locale specific. My sixth result may not be your sixth result. :-)

Comment: The keyword you're looking for is "access modifiers". There is an abundance of resources out there. Public, internal, protected, protected internal, private are all the modifiers.

Comment: Thanks, @KennyEvitt. You just showed me the link that had caused my confusion. Thanks. So, the answer is no.

Comment: The answer is yes, a nested class *can* access the private members of its containing class.

Comment: @Daniel's comment makes more sense when you have a nice way to easily do so, like say, [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/), with which you can easily run snippets of C# code (and VB and F# and some SQL dialects).

Comment: I, and I imagine others, downvoted your question because we were able to answer it ourselves so easily. Stack Overflow isn't really intended to serve as a resource for reference material that's authoritatively maintained elsewhere; in this case the authoritative resource is Microsoft's documentation. However, I realize this is confusing – I'm confused myself sometimes! – because there *are* lots of highly upvoted questions that are in fact bald queries easily answered by standard reference material maintained elsewhere. I'm sorry for the inconsistency of this huge number of people!

Comment: Many times, I have these amnesia attacks where I'll have worked on something extensively just 2 years ago and will have forgotten all about it. If I look up my threads, I see a pattern. I'm asking questions over and over again about things I've worked on before. I've used nested class a gazillion times and even accessed its outer class members from the inner class, but when I am doing something, I find it very efficient to ask here if I can't find the answer after a few searches. My Google skills are not that great. I put in "nested class outer class fields access" before asking this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nested Class has access to the private Members of it's containing type:

```
Class T{
    private static void Foo(){
       // do sth.
    }

    public class InnerClass{
       public static void Bar(){
          Foo(); //no Problem.
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. That was what I was looking for. And so I was right. All the people who down-voted the question, thumbs down to them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes; from [Nested Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173120.aspx):

> A nested type has access to all of the members that are accessible to its containing type. It can access private and protected members of the containing type, including any inherited protected members.

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks. Just what I'd been looking for. I guess I was right. :-)